# How to draw this braid figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, braids

I would like to draw the following figure in the attachment.

[image]

I already  have a code for the two strands in the picture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno,english]{article}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \usetikzlibrary{braids} 
        \begin{document}
            
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, every node/.style={scale=4}]
            \pic[
              rotate=0,
              braid/.cd,
              every strand/.style={ultra thick},
              strand 1/.style={red},
              strand 2/.style={blue},
            ] {braid={s_1}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

But I don't know how to combine these strands with planes. The symbol C in the image file denotes the set of complex numbers.  Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is no attachment, could you check your question again please? Also, please make your code compile so we can copy/paste it please

Comment: Edited it, thank you.

Comment: Hope someone can answer soon!

Comment: Can you please start your code at `\documentclass`, end at `\end{document}` in a way it compiles and shows your result? By doing so I don't need to ask which packages or tikzlibraries you have used ... Thank you (Yes, I know it's braid, but the way it's now imposes the same extra work for anybody trying to help. And can you please remove the dog from the title? Search for briad figure to see what I mean ...)

Comment: I added several packages, I don't think they are necessary but anyway.

Comment: Ok. The trick is to show only those which are needed.

Comment: @elopt Is this your first time with LaTeX? Have you tried compiling the document you posted in your question? The `\usepackage`s must come before `\begin{document}`. You're also loading `graphicx`, `pgfplots` and `tikz-3dplot` even though they don't have anything to do with the question. According to [the `braids` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/braids/0) the `braids` package has been replaced by the `braids` library.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Sorry, my bad,. Now changed it.

Comment: I think you want to change the "briad" in your title to "braid".  (I make typos too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a braid *b* you can access the start and end of strand *i* via the coordinate `(b-i-s)` and `(b-i-e)`. This and other coordinates the pic defines is covered by section 2.2 of [the library's manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/braids/0).

For just planes at the start and at the end, we can use these coordinates and draw a (slanted) rectangle around it. For the bottom one, I'm using the `backgrounds` library and its [`on background layer` key](https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds#tikz/on:background:layer) it provides which makes it easy to draw the rectangle behind the strands.

Adding planes in other points will be an interesting follow-up question. My follow-up question is: Are these planes necessary? Take a look at some of the examples in the manual. Maybe just a line is enough.

The pic also provides access to floors which might be usable here after a few adjustments …

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amssymb} % amssymb for \mathbb
\usetikzlibrary{braids, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
  rectangle around/.style={
    thick, draw, fill=lightgray, xslant=1, fill opacity=.75, rounded corners=+5pt,
    to path={
      ([shift={(-.3,-.2)}]\tikztostart) rectangle node[at end, right]{$#1$}
      ([shift={( .3, .2)}]\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/braid/.append style={/tikz/scale=3}, scale=3]
\pic[
  rotate=0,
  braid/.cd,
  every strand/.style={ultra thick},
  strand 1/.style={red},
  strand 2/.style={blue},
] (b) {braid = s_1};
\path[rectangle around=\mathbb C] (b-1-s) to (b-2-s);
\scoped[on background layer]
  \path[rectangle around=\mathbb C] (b-2-e) to (b-1-e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again. To answer your question: Yes, I need those planes. Probably I will need more than two planes actually. Like a stack of planes.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[blue] (4,1)--(2,-5) node[midway,fill=white] () {\;};
        \draw[red] (2,1)--(4,-5);
        
        \filldraw[gray!30,draw,opacity=.7] (0,0)--(5,0)--(6,2)--(1,2)
        --cycle;
        \filldraw[gray!30,draw,opacity=.7] (0,-6)--(5,-6)--(6,-4)--(1,-4)
        --cycle;
        \node at (6.3,2) () {$\pi_1$};
        \node at (6.3,-4) () {$\pi_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`EDIT`: I changed a little bit the order on the lines in my preceding code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[gray!30,draw,opacity=.7] (0,-6)--(5,-6)--(6,-4)--(1,-4)
        --cycle;
        \draw[blue] (4,1)--(2,-5) node[midway,fill=white] () {\;};
        \draw[red] (2,1)--(4,-5);
        
        \filldraw[gray!30,draw,opacity=.8] (0,0)--(5,0)--(6,2)--(1,2)
        --cycle;
        
        \node at (6.3,2) () {$\pi_1$};
        \node at (6.3,-4) () {$\pi_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

for a better result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can we also make the strands more curved as in my code rather than straight lines?

Comment: @elopt I answered your question. You have another question to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer it looks great. I was wondering is there another way to depict those strands in a more curved way? Because in your code you are using straight lines to picture the strands.

Comment: @elopt In the picture of Your question I see only straight lines.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have also added the code that I'm using to picture braids. Can you see it as well? It is right below the image you are refering to.

Comment: @elopt Your code was edited (changed) after my answer. I tested Your first code. With a lot of errors during compilation...

Comment: My code was wrong,  and I didn't notice it(yikes!). Sorry about that if it took too much time. Again thank you for your answer, it is also very helpful, upvoted.